# Reducing LocationManager accuracy when user is not moving, in background

Tags: ios, swift, scheduled-tasks, core-location, background-process

**Initial premise**: iOS is more likely to deliver timely & reliable background location updates to my app if it only asks for high-accuracy updates occasionally, when needed.  Thus I plan to:

1. drop the location manager to a low accuracy mode when my app enters the background (low battery/resource use, will let us know when the user starts moving)
2. update to to a high accuracy mode when the app receives an update (signifies that the user has started moving and updates are interesting)
3. drop back down to low accuracy mode if/when the user stops moving for a while (no longer need "active" updates, return to state 1)

I'm open to frame challenges if this premise isn't correct.

**Specific question**: How can I implement the accuracy degradation in step 3, given that my app is only being unsuspended in response to location events?  The issue is, if the user stops moving, I won't receive any events and thus my app won't be launched in order for it to *notice* that accuracy can be reduced.

My thought is to implement a deadman timer: trigger a task to run in e.g. five minutes if I *haven't* sent a heartbeat, and send a heartbeat (resetting the timer) every time a meaningful location change is observed.  Is this feasible when running in the background/suspended in iOS?  Would `BGTaskScheduler` serve this purpose if I keep re-submitting triggers for the same identifier, or will iOS consider this spammy and deprioritise the task?

Is there any other built-in functionality that suits my requirements?

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect; you will continue to receive location updates at about 1hz regardless of the accuracy you have requested.  It will just be the same location again and again (in reality the location will shift by a few meters) with different horizontal accuracy values. . There is no way you can schedule a 5 minute timer if your app is in the background.

Comment: @Paulw11 I've been seeing background location updates stop coming through after a while, and based on other SO and Apple forum posts it seems other developers had a similar problem and solved it by reducing location accuracy.  I appreciate it is opaque as to how exactly iOS decides when and how often to unsuspend the app.